# InsertOnSubmit doesn't attach?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

After creating a new object (Foo), I set the key (BarId) for an EntityRef association property (Bar).  I then want to insert the new object into the database, and be able to access the lazy-loaded child object afterward.

Unfortunately, the lazy-loading property returns null after the call to InsertOnSubmit().  It returns the correct object if I instead Attach() the object to the data context, however.

*Here's code that successfully inserts my new object into the database, but doesn't correctly setup lazy-loading for the child Bar property:*

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.BarId = 123;
context.GetTable<Foo> ().InsertOnSubmit( foo );
foo.Bar.Something();    // throws NullReferenceException
```

*Here, the Bar object is properly loaded:*

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.BarId = 123;
context.GetTable<Foo> ().Attach( foo );
foo.Bar.Something();    // method is called on lazy-loaded Bar object
```

Calling Attach before InsertOnSubmit causes the latter to throw a "Cannot add an entity that already exists" exception.

So, is this a bug in LINQ-to-SQL, where inserted objects are not properly attached to the data context?

How do I fix this?

Comment: When using InsertOnSubmit, you need SaveChanges to submit the new object to the data store.  This could be the problem, since creating a new data item does not innately associate a data context to it (to lazy load from) until the object is populated by the context (I think).

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately, I've built a security layer on top of my data context that checks object/user permissions before calling SubmitChanges().  That code needs to access certain properties of my objects, including ones that are lazy-loaded.  Whether that is a good idea is questionable, but it's what I have to work with now.

Comment: @NickLarsen: I just tested this, and you are correct.  The lazy-loading works after calling SubmitChanges().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the Bar property instead of the BarId property of your Foo class. In my opinion what Linq-to-sql does wrong here is to have the BarId property in the first place. It doesn't add any value and It goes against core principals of OOP. So, I would change your code to something like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = //get bar with id: 123;
context.GetTable<Foo> ().InsertOnSubmit(foo);
foo.Bar.Something();
```

Comment: That makes sense.  The only downside is now I need to add a small amount of extra complexity to my code by explicitly querying for Bar, rather than just setting an ID.

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion its a lot better. It looks a lot better from a OO perspective. Just look at other ORM's like EF or nhibernate.